# General OPE for a primary field with itself

Tags: conformal-field-theory

I am working through the book Statistical Field Theory [Giuseppe Mussardo 2nd Ed] for CFT.
In the problem session, there is

> [10.6. Operator product expansion in the channel of the identity operator]
> Let $\phi_i(z)$ a primary field of a CFT with central charge $c$. Let $\Delta_i$ be its conformal weight. Prove that the Ward identity uniquely fixes the first terms of the operator expansion in the channel of the identity operator, namely
> $$
> \phi_i(z)\phi_i(w) = \frac{1}{(z-w)^{2\Delta_i}}\left[1+\frac{2\Delta_i}{c}T(w)+...\right].
> $$

1. In terms of fusion rules, it means $[\phi]\times [\phi]= [1]+...$ am I correct?
2. When I tried to naively check the validity of the equation say apply $T(x)$ on the left
   we have
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   LHS=T(x)\phi_i(z)\phi_i(w) = \frac{\Delta_i}{(x-z)^2}\phi_i(z) \phi_i(w) + \frac{1}{x-z}(\partial_z\phi_i(z))\phi_i(w)
   \end{aligned}
   $$
   and
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   RHS&=\frac{1}{(z-w)^{2\Delta_i}}\left[T(x)+\frac{2\Delta_i}{c}T(x)T(w)+...\right]\\
   &=\frac{1}{(z-w)^{2\Delta_i}}\left[T(x)+\frac{2\Delta_i}{c}\left(\frac{c/2}{(x-w)^4}+\frac{2T(w)}{(x-w)^2}\right)+...\right]
   \end{aligned}
   $$
   The leading term of identity operator for LHS seems to be
   $$
   \frac{\Delta_i}{(x-z)^2(z-w)^{2\Delta_i}}+\frac{-2\Delta_i}{(x-z)(z-w)^{2\Delta+1}}
   $$
   while for RHS it is
   $$
   \frac{\Delta_i}{(x-w)^4 (z-w)^{2\Delta_i}}
   $$
   they are not even of the same dimension. Did I make mistakes somewhere in the derivation?
3. Any strategy for proving this equality?

Best

---

Edit: As Professor Ribault pointed out the dimension analysis shows the initial equation can not be correct but this is indeed the original claim from the book.
The screenshot of Page 397 for this book https://academic.oup.com/book/43943
[image]

And there seems to be no corrigenda for it.

So I guess the correct the correct claim should be
$$
\phi_i(z)\phi_i(w) =\frac{1}{(z-w)^{2\Delta_i}}\left[1+ b* (z-w)^2T(w)+...\right]
$$
where $b$ is a constant.

Comment: The equation you quote for $\phi_i(z)\phi_i(w)$ already has a problem with dimensional analysis. Did you (or the book) forget a factor $(z-w)^2$ in front of the $T(w)$?

Comment: @SylvainRibault, Hi Professor Ribault thanks for pointing out the defects. I have edited the question. I have a naive argument. Because $\langle\phi_i(z)\phi_i(w)\rangle$ is invariant under exchanging $z$ and $w$ so the OPE should have only even order of $(z-w)$ so we start from $L_{-2}$ and $L_{-1} L_{-1}$ in the conformal family of identity operators. And then we apply $T(x)$ from left to determine the coefficients. Would that work?

Comment: Yes, $\phi_i(z)\phi_i(w)$ is invariant under $z\leftrightarrow w$, but the OPE is not, because we are expanding near a given $w$, thus breaking the invariance. The reason why there is no term of the first order is because $L_{-1}=\partial_w$ kills the identity field. For the same reason there is no term with $L_{-1}^2$. Your method of inserting $T$ and using OPE associativity is in principle correct and it should eventually work.